# Creating multiple swagger docs in the same project

Tags: c#, swagger, api-design

I wondered if anyone has experience creating multiple api's and swagger documents with versioning within the same c# project.

I'm creating a api with multiple areas. I want each area to have its own swagger doc with versioning.

area 1 - url http://someapi.com/api1/swagger
-v1
-v2
area 2 - url http://someapi.com/api2/swagger
-v1
-v2

I have tried to configure this in swagger, but it seems like you can only have one swagger instance pr project. Is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by one swagger instance but different groups. Basically, you would have multiple swagger docs. So first you can use `ApiExplorerSettings` on your controllers you categorize your APIs based on the area.

```cs
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "AreaOne")]
public class AreaOneController : BaseController
{
  // some stuff
}

//-----

[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "AreaTwo")]
public class AreaTwoController : BaseController
{
  // some stuff
}
```

And when you want to inject swagger:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    // Space
    c.SwaggerDoc("AreaOne",
        new OpenApiInfo { Title = "AreaOne Api", Version = "v1" });

    // Access
    c.SwaggerDoc("AreaTwo",
        new OpenApiInfo { Title = "AreaTwo Api", Version = "v1" });

// other configs
}

 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
 {

     c.ShowCommonExtensions();

     c.SwaggerEndpoint("AreaOne/swagger.json", "AreaOne");
     c.SwaggerEndpoint("AreaTwo/swagger.json","AreaTwo Api");

}
```

And you will have multiple docs like this (different names):

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. When you have this configuration of swagger how do you handle versioning?

Comment: @user23137202 You need to get Api version in the route like ``areaOne/v{apiVersion}/something``